# Sort input files after selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there any way for me to sort files for POST to server using any client side solution?

More specific, i am using the following tag `<input type="file" name="Myfiles[]" multiple>` To choose some images.

With the code at the end i display a preview of the images and using jQuery UI sortable i'm able to change the position of the elements.

So, when i post the data to the server how can i insert the files in the order of the sort? that's the point where i'm stuck

```
    for(var i = 0; i< this.files.length; i++)
     {
            var file = this.files[i];
            if(!file.type.match(‘image’))
                continue;
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.addEventListener('load',function(event){
                var picFile = event.target;
                $('#sortable').append('<li><img height="100" width="100" src="'+picFile.result+'" /></li>');
            });
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

Comment: You need to be more clear.  You don't show a POST operation and don't show where you receive the posted files.

Comment: You can force a index into Myfiles array. AngularJS example: Myfiles[{{ index }}]

Comment: @AbraCadaver the Post operation is not important, processing an array of data from an input file is a single operation and they get inserted in the order they were selected during the onchange event, not the final order of the previews.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are storing the files into an array:

```
var storedFiles = [];
```

You can create a hidden field to store the IDs of the images in the order you want (3,1,2,4..) These IDs must be generated after your images are selected.

Then when the upload button is clicked, grab the sorted contents of the hidden input field and run a for loop to reprocess the order of the files.

```
var data = new FormData();
var items_array = $('.cvf_hidden_field').val();
var items = items_array.split(',');

for (var i in items){
    var item_number = items[i];
    data.append('files' + i, storedFiles[item_number]);
}
```

Then append the sorted files into the variable data, then send it using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the server receives the files will be the order in which they were placed in the form to be submitted to the server.

That means it's probably easier to re-order them client-side before submitting e.g. by re-ordering the order in which they appear in the form for submission.  Heres a rough-and-ready snippet of what you could use:

```
   var newOrder = [];
   for(var i = 0; i< this.files.length; i++){
              var indiv_file = this.files[a];

              // processing to calculate desired array position for submission         
              idealPos = function_returning_new_array_position(indiv_file);
              newOrder[idealPos] = this.files[a];


   }
```

Thus re-order your 'this.files' array to reflect your chosen order. And use the newOrder array in the form when you submit the files. I can't quite make out what you're doing in the above code, but unless your users are expecting their images to be re-ordered, it could turn out a bit disorienting to see the files they are planning to submit jumping around.

Answer (score -1):

You can use plain JavaScript code to sort the files using the file names and store them as an array.

```
var files = evt.target.files

var RESULT = []
var m = files.length
for (var a = 0; a < m; a++) {
    var min = 0
    for (var b = 0; b < (m - 1) - a; b++) {
        if ((files[b].name).localeCompare(files[b + 1].name) == 1) {
            min = b + 1
        }
    }
    RESULT[a] = files[min]
    delete files[min]
}
```

The above code sorts the uploaded files in ascending order based on the file name and stores it in RESULT.